# Как разделить строку?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка построенная по правилам. "Город [синоним1, .., синонимN] {ссылка}, Город2 [] {}]" текста в квадратных и\или фигурных скобках может не быть. Пример

```
    String input = "Москва [Мск, Белокаменная] {msk.com}, Санкт-Петербург [Спб, Питер], Ростов, Калининград [Кёниг] {123.com}";
```

Нужно регулярное выражение, чтобы поделить на части

1. Москва [Мск, Белокаменная] {msk.com}
2. Санкт-Петербург [Спб, Питер]
3. Ростов
4. Калининград [Кёниг] {123.com}

И затем нужно каждую строку разделить на Город,синонимы и ссылки

1. Москва
2. [Мск, Белокаменная]
3. {msk.com}

как я понял тут надо вводить условия для предшествующего текста вида `"?<=\\{*\\})||(?<=[*]), ?"`
Подскажите, как составить?

Comment: `input.split(",")` - получаешь массив строк для первой части вопроса. потом каждую строчку из полученного массива делаешь `.split(" ")` и получаешь массив строк для 2ой части вопроса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```
"(?U)(\\w+(?:-\\w+)*)(?:\\s*(?:\\[([^\\]\\[]*)]))?(?:,?\\s*\\{([^{}]*)\\})?"
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/MoYdEP/3). Подробности:

- `(?U)` - `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` - включает поддержку Юникода `\w`
- `(\w+(?:-\w+)*)` - Подмаска №1: один и более буквоцифровых символов, за которыми могут следовать 0 и более повторов символа `-` и один и более буквоцифровых символов
- `(?:\s*\[([^\]\[]*)])?` - опциональная последовательность 0 и более пробельных символов, затем `[`, 0 и более символов, отличных от `]` и `[` (Подмаска №2), а затем `]`
- `(?:,?\s*\{([^{}]*)\})?` - опциональная последовательность необязательной запятой, 0 и более пробельных символов, затем `{`, 0 и более символов, отличных от `}` и `{` (Подмаска №3), а затем `}`.

[Код на Java:](https://ideone.com/j1gMR8)

```
String input = "Москва [Мск, Белокаменная] {msk.com}, Санкт-Петербург [Спб, Питер], Ростов, Калининград [Кёниг] {123.com}\nРостов {123.com}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?U)(\\w+(?:-\\w+)*)(?:\\s*(?:\\[([^\\]\\[]*)]))?(?:,?\\s*\\{([^{}]*)\\})?");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println("-------------\nСовпадение: " + matcher.group());
    System.out.println("Подмаска №1: " + matcher.group(1));
    if (matcher.group(2) != null) {
        System.out.println("Подмаска №2: " + matcher.group(2)); 
    }
    if (matcher.group(3) != null) {
        System.out.println("Подмаска №3: " + matcher.group(3)); 
    }
}
```

Результат:

```js
-------------
Совпадение: Москва [Мск, Белокаменная] {msk.com}
Подмаска №1: Москва
Подмаска №2: Мск, Белокаменная
Подмаска №3: msk.com
-------------
Совпадение: Санкт-Петербург [Спб, Питер]
Подмаска №1: Санкт-Петербург
Подмаска №2: Спб, Питер
-------------
Совпадение: Ростов
Подмаска №1: Ростов
-------------
Совпадение: Калининград [Кёниг] {123.com}
Подмаска №1: Калининград
Подмаска №2: Кёниг
Подмаска №3: 123.com
-------------
Совпадение: Ростов {123.com}
Подмаска №1: Ростов
Подмаска №3: 123.com
```

Comment: Ростов должен быть отдельной записью. Просто у него нет синонимов и ссылки.

Comment: @AntonCharov Так добавьте запятую, `(\w(?:[^,\[]*\w)?)(?:\s*(?:\[([^\]\[]*)]))?(?:,?\s*\{([^{}]*)\})?`

Comment: а вот такой вариант не проходит "Ростов {123.com}" В первую подмаску попадает "Ростов {123.com"

Comment: @AntonCharov Да, я думал и о таком варианте после того, как понял, что совпадения разделены запятой. Ответ обновлён.

Comment: А если в первом выражении может быть любое количество слов через пробел и с символами кроме , и [] {} - которые используются для разделения, то нужно будет перечислить все возможные символы? (?U)(\\w+(?:[-,+,!, ]+\\w+)*)(?:\\s*(?:\\[([^\\]\\[]*)]))?(?:,?\\s*\\{([^{}]*)\\})?

Comment: Пример https://ideone.com/L8wAbl

Comment: @AntonCharov Да вроде вы всё правильно сделали. Только в символьном классе не надо экранировать фигурные скобки - https://ideone.com/rbzBdf.

Answer (score 1):

Для второй части задачи здесь подойдёт функция `.split(" ")`, когда разбиваешь каждую часть по пробелу.

Для первой задачи будет мало разбить текст по запятой, потому что запятая может быть как и разделителем частей, так и находиться в блоке перечисления между `{` `}` и `[` `]`. Решение для первой части может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
List<String> parts = new ArrayList<>();
int bracketsCounter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    String symbol = String.valueOf(input.charAt(i));
    if ("({[".contains(symbol)) bracketsCounter++;
    else if (")}]".contains(symbol)) bracketsCounter--;

    if (symbol.equals(",") && bracketsCounter == 0) {
        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            parts.add(sb.toString());
            sb = new StringBuilder();
        }
    } else {
        sb.append(symbol);
    }
}

if (sb.length() > 0) {
    parts.add(sb.toString());
}
```